# Create an Endless Item picker with PageView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

please i'm creating an Item picker with PageView the always put the selected item on center. it seems to be correct with`pageSnapping: true` but the probleme is, when i reach the end, there's space on the screen.
[remove the space on right when the end is reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MVae.png).

i can user `padEnds: true,` to remove that space but the selected item will not longer be on the middle.

imagine i have 15 items, what i want is when the PageView Shows the 15th item (selected), continue by showing from the first item (Make it infinit scroll)

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  late int _currentPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentPage = 3;
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 3,
      viewportFraction: 1/4
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 0.2,
          child: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: 16,
            pageSnapping: true,
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              setState(() => _currentPage=page);
            },
            itemBuilder: (_, index)
            {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _pageController.animateToPage(
                      index,
                      curve: Curves.linear,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 320)
                    );
                  });
                },

                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: index==0 ? 0 : 10,
                    right: index==15 ? 0 : 10,
                  ),
                  child: PhysicalModel(
                    elevation: 4,
                    color: (index==_currentPage) ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    child: Center(child: Text(index.toString()))
                  )
                )
              );
            }
          )
        ))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

i need to end up with something like this.
[the final result i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuHQH.png)

thank you so much.